# TIGER Geocoder / PostGIS - get county from point

Tags: postgis, sql, tiger, postgresql

Looking for some help with getting the county for a lat/lon. I have PostGIS / TIGER Geocoder installed and can reverse look up a point and get the addresses. I would like to get the county the addresses are in.

I have...

```
geocoder=# SELECT pprint_addy(r.addy[1]) As st1, pprint_addy(r.addy[2]) As st2, pprint_addy(r.addy[3]) As st3, 
    array_to_string(r.street, ',') As cross_streets 
    FROM reverse_geocode(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-77.03 38.90)',4269),false) As r;
            st1                 |            st2             | st3 |   cross_streets    
------------------------------------+----------------------------+-----+--------------------
New York Ave, Washington, DC 20005 | H St, Washington, DC 20005 |     | H St NW,13th St NW
```

(1 row)

And would now like to get the county for that point.

Answer (score 3):

Silly me... 
select * from geocoder.tiger_data.county_all ca where ST_Contains(the_geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-77.03 38.90)',4269))